# puzzled by compiler warning that suggests compound assignment of int8_t promotes to int

Tags: c++, c, standards, icc

I can usually understand the reason behind a compiler warning, but this one seems just plain wrong.

```
#include <stdint.h>    
uint8_t myfunc(uint8_t x,uint8_t y)
{
    x |= y;
    return x;
}
```

The intel compiler with -Wall complains:

```
conversion from "int" to "uint8_t={unsigned char}" may lose significant bits
  x |= y;
    ^
```

Is this right?  Is the above code non-portable and non-standard somehow?

Comment: To summarize the comments in the accepted answer: the compiler is technically right that there is a conversion from int to uint8_t, but it is disappointingly daft and wrong in the claim that it may lose significant bits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's `integer promotions` at work.

in

```
x |= y;
```

both operands of the `|` operator are promoted to `int`

```
x = (int)x | (int)y;
```

then the result is converted back to `uint8_t` losing precision.

Comment: The warning says "may lose significant bits". That's blatantly wrong. No bits can be lost by this operation.

Comment: The compiler is of course free to optimize the code and do it all in 8 bits. It will still give the warning though.

Comment: @R, the conversion from `int` or `unsigned int` to `uint8_t` can potentially lose bits. Recognizing that there are no significant bits to lose would be too much trouble for the compiler writer with very little gain.

Comment: The compiler is of course free to issue warnings if you don't adhere to GNU Coding Standards for brace indention, but most users would find that incredibly annoying and wrong. Similarly, this warning is wrong. It's blindly looking only at the *type* of the expression, and not the *possible range of values* of the expression, to issue the warnings. If it used the latter, which would make a lot more sense, it would easily see that the potential range of values is 0-255 and shut up.

Comment: Note that there are many reasons the compiler should already be keeping track of the potential range of values - for example, if `x|y` were used in `switch (x|y)`, you would definitely want to know that `x|y` is in the range 0-255 to use a jumptable without an additional conditional to check range...

Comment: @R..: It's even easier than range analysis here (which may require flow analysis), gcc could realize than some operators (`|`, `^`, `&`) do not augment the range of a value, and thus that `uint8_t | uint8_t` necessarily fits into a `uint8_t`. It seems like they postpone this analysis to later (after type promotion) and have failed to take this into account... Of course I would support any form of lightweight range analysis too, but it's far more complicated :)

Comment: Add `%`, `/`, and `>>` to the list, and of course note that all the logical operators have 1-bit range. (Does it currently give a warning for `uint8_t x = !foo;`??)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the input on what is happening behind the scenes with the integer promotion.   I am concluding the intel compiler warnings are given with far too rough granularity and far too low a Signal:Noise ratio to be useful.  The fact that I was blissfully ignorant of this detail of a language I've been using heavily for 20 years just goes to show how ridiculous. I don't expect this sort of compiler warning unless I ask for pedantic warnings.

Comment: You are wrong in "both operands of the | operator are promoted to int. 
`x = (int)x | (int)y;`". The intel compiler does it like `x = x | (int)y;` actually.

Answer (score 5):

It is right. The operator promotes the argument(s) to `int`. See [this page](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html#section-1.1) for more details, the first sentence begins:

> No arithmetic is done by C at a precision shorter than int [...]

Answer (score 4):

The values of `x` and `y` are promoted to `int` for the computation, but the warning is nonetheless bogus. The `|` operator cannot increase the width in bits of the result beyond the widths of the operands, which already fit in `uint8_t` since they were promoted from `uint8_t`. The vast majority of things this warning option flags are completely valid and correct code, and unless you want to waste your time on 100 questions like this, I think it's best to turn off or ignore those warnings.

Comment: Don't turn off the warnings there are some cases where you mistakenly weren't prepared for implicit promotion.  Say you had an unsigned being promoted to signed in a loop by accident, you'd want to know about that.

Comment: @AJG85: But the question is *would you know about it?* - when the warning is buried amount hundreds of other bogus warnings generated by this option. That's why it's so important for compiler writers to fix warnings so that they only trigger in situations where something is actually likely to be wrong. If they flood you with bogus warnings, you'll either (1) ignore them, or (2) turn off the option. I consider option (2) slightly better, since it avoids hiding *other types of warnings*, which may have a higher signal to noise ratio, amid the flood of bogus warnings.

Comment: I'd pose this question _is fighting with the compiler worth saving a few bytes of memory?_ You could probably only answer yes to that less than to knowing whether a warning is real and what to do about it. I don't have warnings but I also don't use `unsigned char` when doing `signed int` operations either.

Comment: Well if you just used `int` for the arguments and return value, the warnings in the function would go away, but when you assigned it back into a `uint8_t`, the warning would reappear at that point... I don't really see any way around it when small types are in use.

Comment: If the x or y is negative, will promotion increase "width in bits"?

Comment: Promotion from a smaller signed type to a larger unsigned type will increase the width of the value. Promotion from a smaller signed type to a larger signed type will not increase the width of the value.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler warning might seem nonsensical because the operation can't possibly produce more than 8 bits, but it's just a subset of a larger class of operations which can. For example, if you replaced the `|=` with `+=`, the possibility of overflow becomes very real.

The way to eliminate the warning is to tell the compiler that you're consciously throwing away the bits with a cast:

```
x = (uint8_t)(x | y);
```

Comment: @R, sure you are, it's just that you already know they're all zero. Perhaps I should rephrase it to "consciously ignoring the upper bits".